# AppHarbor MVC C# App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filesystems, appharbor

I've recently built a web application using ASP.NET MVC C#. In the app I give users the ability to upload images. This works as expected locally but on the server I have a strange issue that I (with my limited knowledge) can't explain. Images load as expected but only every second time the page is loaded.

To test this try:

```
http://watchdocumetaries.com/Content/img/profile/admin.jpg
```

This isn't a controller/action it's simply a file. If you visit once the image loads, the second time you get a 404. Hit F5, it goes image->404->image->404. I really have no idea what's going on here.

Also, I have message functionality that that uses TempData to display a message to the user, eg. "You have uploaded a new image". This also seems to be having issues as it only displays on the second refresh.

Comment: I guess when it 404's it's actually a server error but the error page cannot be found so it returns 404. Try checking your server/error logs for more info

Comment: btw: for me it was 404->404->404->image when I tried to see your example

Comment: Strange, this is really confusing me. I thought this may have been something to do with me being logged in so I logged out and it still behaves in the same manner. This is weird.

Comment: Ok, something is fundamentally wrong here. I uploaded a new image as the profile image and now instead of switching between a 404 and the profile image it switches between the last image and the new one.

Comment: Also I don't know if this is related but any data sent over in TempData only appears after a couple of requests have been made. I have no idea how to debug whats going on here.

Comment: Can you check appharbor error logs on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

The issue was that I had the application setup on AppHarbor using 2 worker units. I reduced this to one and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Note that AppHarbor worker filesystems are ephemeral and are not persisted between deploys or restarts. Consider uploading to AWS S3 or similar. Guide: http://blog.appharbor.com/2013/01/10/asynchronous-browser-uploads-to-s3-and-gcs-using-cors-aspnet-mvc